# C# get all AOIs from list in which lies a specific point

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

I have a `List of AOIs` (area of interest) where AOI is defined by 2 points top-left and bottom-right corner (Start and End points).

And I have a point defined by `PosX and PosY`.

I want to get all such AOIs from list in which specific point lies. How can I do it most effectively? I wanted to do it with select and where functions with lambda expressions but can't figure out how to achieve it.

I created rectangle bounding an AOI and tested if a point lies in it:

```
var rect = new RectangleF(aoi.Start.X, aoi.Start.Y, aoi.End.X - aoi.Start.X, aoi.End.Y - aoi.Start.Y));
var liesIn = rect.Contains(pt.PosX, pt.PosY);
```

But I have an `List<AOIs>`. If I want all AOIs from list which contains point `pt` must I iterate through all list or can I do it somehow effectively?

**EDIT:** ok I figured it out. This works for me.

```
var result = AOIs.Where(a => new RectangleF(a.Start.X, a.Start.Y, a.Start.X - a.End.X, a.Start.Y - a.End.Y).Contains(pt.PosX, pt.PosY)).ToList();
```

I don't know what was with me I was doing some weird things but solution is easy.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose something like this:

```
AOIs.Where(x => 
    x.Start.X < posX
 && x.Start.Y < posY 
 && x.End.X > posX 
 && x.End.Y > posY)
```

Comment: Yes could be. I just now wrote this `AOIs.Where(a => new RectangleF(a.Start.X, a.Start.Y, a.Start.X - a.End.X, a.Start.Y - a.End.Y).Contains(pt.PosX, pt.PosY)).ToList();` But must test it if it works correctly.

Comment: I think your solution would also work but I will keep mine :D Thanks